# How to fix the alignment of my cards? Using Vue and Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, frontend, vuetify.js

Hey so I'm building a article curation platform and they are presented in the form of cards provided by the Vuetify library.

I'm having problem aligning them properly.

[image: Image showing several cards, where the last card if offset by a half card's width]

If you see the image, you can see at the last row, the second card doesn't seem to align in the centre and puts off all the alignment.

What I have done is as such

```
<v-container grid-list-md fluid>
  <v-layout align-start row wrap pb-4 justify-start>
    <v-flex :key="cards.id"pt-3 v-for="cards in searchbar">
      <v-card hover class="card" @click="linkClick(cards.link)">
```

Comment: If you will always have a known number per row then use the Vuetify grid system. `<v-flex xs4 ...>` will allow 3 per row and stack the way you want.

Comment: perfect that did it!